# Using OS X APIs directly from Embarcadero Delphi

Tags: delphi, pascal

I am working on a Delphi FMX application that uses Bonjour for broadcasting and discovering devices on the local network.  On the Mac side, there is an interface named [`NSNetServiceDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnetservicedelegate), but it is not implemented in the interface of Delphi's `Macapi.Foundation` unit.  This delegate will discover and resolve services on the local network.  Since it is not implemented, I get Access Violations.

I know it is possible to use Bonjour on the Apple side, but I don't know how to set it up.

I found this: [Using OS X APIs directly from Delphi](http://delphiblog.twodesk.com/using_os_x_apis_directly_from_delphi), but it is working with an interface that was implemented on the Delphi side.

How can I structure my code to gain access to something not yet implemented in Delphi?

Comment: See [Quickly Auto Generate iOS, OSX, And Android Headers For Delphi And C++Builder](https://blogs.embarcadero.com/quickly-auto-generate-ios-osx-and-android-headers-for-delphi-and-c-builder/) in Embarcadero's Blog

Comment: I've generated imports for `NSNetServiceDelegate` and associated classes/protocols, here: https://gist.github.com/DelphiWorlds/446b65529b22c21e2d2abacd0b852b79

Comment: I also suggest watching this video, from the 25m 10s mark, regarding implementing delegates (it's for iOS, but it's the same principle on macOS):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yf9LxQYl5LA. Very important part starts at 26m 10s

Comment: [Linking the YT video at 26:10](https://youtu.be/Yf9LxQYl5LA?t=1570)

Comment: The delegate was in Remy's GitHub.  What do I do with it now?  Do I replace the stub in Macapi.Foundation.pas?

Comment: You don't need to modify `Macapi.Foundation.pas`. You can have the declaration in a separate unit and use that unit

Comment: Thank you.  I used a combination of the self generated headers and now in my app Bonjour is listening.  I would like to use that application but it didn't detect C lang.